# Python numpy method matrix.toFile()

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, output

I need help formatting my matrix when i write it to a file. I am using the numpy method called toFile()
it takes 3 args. 1-name of file,2-seperator(must be a string),3-format(Also a string)
I dont know a lot about formatting but i am trying to format the file to there is a new line each 9 charatcers. (not including spaces). The output is a 9x9 soduku game. So I need to it be formatted 9x9.

```
finished = M.tofile("soduku_solved.txt", " ", "")
```

Where M is a matrix

My first argument is the name of the file, the second is a space, but I dont know what format argument i need to to make it 9x9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think that's possible with the numpy tofile function. I think the format argument just allows you to format how each individual item is formatted, it doesn't consider them in a group.

You could do something like:

```
M = np.random.randint(1, 9, (9, 9))

each_item_fmt = '{:>3}'
each_row_fmt = ' '.join([each_item_fmt] * 9)
fmt = '\n'.join([each_row_fmt] * 9)

as_string = fmt.format(*M.flatten())
```

It's not a very nice way to build up the format string and there's bound to be a better way of doing it. You'll see the final result (`print(fmt)`) is a big block of '{:>3}', which basically says, put a bit of data in here with a fixed width of 3 characters, right aligned.

EDIT Since you're putting it directly into a file you could write it line by line:

```
M = np.random.randint(1, 9, (9, 9))

fmt = ('{:>3} ' * 9).strip()

with open('soduku_solved.txt', 'w') as f:
    for m in M:
        f.write(fmt.format(*m) + '\n')
```